# CodeIgniter URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

Hi everyone I am having a problem in setting up the .htaccess URL fix for CodeIgniter Framework.

I have a site launched in a folder named "sites".

***=> THE PROBLEM:***

**This URL works perfectly:

```
http://127.0.0.1/sites/home/index/test
```

**I want to get rid of /index/ from the URL**

The destination URL should be like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/sites/home/test
```

**How can i acheive this URL?**

### *Additional Info:*

**I have URL helper in autoload done which works great and here is the code in My Controller**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index($var='')
{
   echo $var; //outputs -> test
}

}
```

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteBase /sites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Check Youn's answer below. You will need to create a catch all route. This will catch all requests to the home controller and re-route them to the index() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you want to add a route in config/routes.php:

route['home/(:any)'] = "home/index";

Comment: In order to make the variable accessible via the index() functions parameters you could even do: `route['home/(:any)'] = "home/index/$1";`

Comment: WOW! this is exactly what I needed, it worked like a charm! its a simple and efficient solution.
Thank you Buddy!